# java array returned with incorrect values

Tags: java, arrays

I am a TA for a java class at my university and a student confronted me with a very odd problem today in lab. I looked over it for about an hour and had the other TA in lab do the same, yet we could not find a problem.

Effectively what we are doing here is creating 3 arrays, passing them into a new method. Modifying the value of those array in the new method and returning back to the original method. We are not using the return statement to return any of the arrays to the original method. Instead we are levering, what I can only describe being from a C background as pass-by-reference. However upon returning to the original method that values have changed to some incorrect values.

In this specific example we have three arrays called: "exams", "quizzes" and "labs." Each of these arrays are of size 1,000 and are initialized to -1. Inside the first method "calcGrade" we create these arrays and initialize them. Then we pass all three arrays to the second method which captures the amount of exams, quizzes and labs the user has and then stores the actual exam, quiz and lab grade values to the arrays.

METHOD 1 (calcGrade)

```
exams            quizzes           labs
 -1                 -1              -1
 -1                 -1              -1
 -1                 -1              -1
 -1                 -1              -1
  .                  .               .
  .                  .               .
  .                  .               .
```

METHOD 2 (getScores)

```
exams            quizzes           labs
 90                 80             90
-1                  80             90
-1                 -1              -1
-1                 -1              -1
 .                  .               .
 .                  .               .
 .                  .               .
```

BACK to METHOD 1 (calcGrades)

```
exams            quizzes           labs
80                 90              90
-1                 -1              90
-1                 -1              -1
-1                 -1              -1
 .                  .               .
 .                  .               .
 .                  .               .
```

Can anyone think of any reason this could be happening? I am honestly stumped and I don't want him to lose credit for something that doesn't seem to be wrong...

Here is the code (please note that there are several println statements in there for debugging purposes):

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

 public class CSE1341Grade{

    public static void main(String [] args){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("What is your first name?  ");
        String first = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("What is your last name?  ");
        String last = input.nextLine();

        calcGrade(first, last);

    }
    public static void calcGrade(String first, String last){

        int base = 1000;
        int[] quizzes = new int [base];
        int[] exams = new int [base];
        int[] labs = new int [base];
        for(int x = 0; x < base; x++)
        {
            quizzes[x] = -1;
            exams[x] = -1;
            labs[x] = -1;
        }

        int[] countarr = getScores(quizzes, exams, labs);
        System.out.println("EXAMS:");
        for(int x = 0; x < countarr[0]; x++)
            System.out.println(exams[x]);

        System.out.println("QUIZ:");
        for(int x = 0; x < countarr[1]; x++)
            System.out.println(quizzes[x]);

        System.out.println("LABS:");
        for(int x = 0; x < countarr[2]; x++)
            System.out.println(labs[x]);

        for(int x = 0; x < countarr.length; x++)
            System.out.println(countarr[x]);
        //System.out.println("----");
        double examAvg =0.0;
        for(int i=0;i<countarr[0];i++){            //adding together scores
            examAvg+=exams[i];
            //System.out.println(examAvg);
        }
        //System.out.println("----");
        double quizAvg=0.0;
        for(int i=0;i<countarr[1];i++){            //adding together scores
            quizAvg+=quizzes[i];
            //System.out.println(quizAvg);
        }
        //System.out.println("----");
        double labAvg=0.0;
        for(int i=0;i<countarr[2];i++){                  //adding together scores
            labAvg+=labs[i];
            //System.out.println(labAvg);
        }

        examAvg = examAvg/countarr[0];

        quizAvg = quizAvg/countarr[1];

        labAvg = labAvg/countarr[2];

        double totalAverage = (.5 * examAvg) + (.35 * quizAvg) + (.1 *labAvg) + 5.0;

        System.out.println("Total Score: " +totalAverage);//display average

        String grade = "";

        if (totalAverage >= 90)
            grade = "A";
        else if (totalAverage >= 80)
            grade ="B";
        else if (totalAverage >= 70)
            grade = "C";
        else
            grade = "F";

        System.out.println(first + " " + last + " your grade is a: " + grade); //letter grade

    }
    public static int [] getScores(int [] exams, int [] quizzes, int [] labs){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int [] countArray = new int[3];             //holding numbers of exams quizzes labs

        System.out.println("How many exam grades do you have? ");
        countArray[0] = input.nextInt(); 
        System.out.println("How many quiz grades do you have? ");
        countArray[1] = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("How many lab grades do you have?" );
        countArray[2] = input.nextInt();

        System.out.println(countArray[0] + ", " + countArray[1] + ", " + countArray[2]);

        for(int counter = 0; counter < countArray[0]; counter++){  //every exam score
            System.out.printf("Enter Exam" + " " + (counter + 1) + " " + "score: ");
            exams[counter]=input.nextInt();
            System.out.println(exams[counter]);
        }
        System.out.println("----");

        for(int counter = 0; counter < countArray[1]; counter++){  //every quiz score
            System.out.printf("Enter Quiz" + " " + (counter + 1) + " " + "score: ");
            quizzes[counter]=input.nextInt();
            System.out.println(quizzes[counter]);
            }
        System.out.println("----");

        for(int counter = 0; counter < countArray[2]; counter++){  //every lab score
            System.out.printf("Enter Lab" + " " + (counter + 1) + " " + "score: ");
            labs[counter]=input.nextInt();
            System.out.println(labs[counter]);
        }
        System.out.println("----");

        System.out.println("EXAMS:");
        for(int x = 0; x < countArray[0]; x++)
            System.out.println(exams[x]);

        System.out.println("QUIZ:");
        for(int x = 0; x < countArray[1]; x++)
            System.out.println(quizzes[x]);

        System.out.println("LABS:");
        for(int x = 0; x < countArray[2]; x++)
            System.out.println(labs[x]);

        System.out.println("************************");

        return countArray;                    //return back to calc grade
    }
    }
```

Comment: Please boil down the code to the simplest possible state that still produces the same problem. Doing so will 1) make it easier for us to help you and 2) perhaps let you spot the problem yourself.

Comment: Also it's a common misconception that Java objects are passed by reference. They're actually passed by *value* of the reference, which is not the same.

Comment: @arshajii - What's the difference between "pass by reference" and "pass by value of the reference"? They both pass the address of the object. The confusion is in thinking that non-primitive Java variables and fields are objects when they are never more than references to objects.

Comment: @TedHopp They are different. If Java was truly pass by reference when it came to objects, then we could reassign an object parameter and the reassignment would show up in whatever variable we passed to the function. This is not the case in Java. *A* reference is still passed because we can mutate the object and the change persists, this is what we mean by *value* of the reference. This is described in more detail here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference.

Comment: @arshajii - Java is strictly call by value. However, when you declare something like `String x = "hello";`, then the value of `x` is _not_ the `String` object, but a _reference_ to it. The object itself is, in fact, passed by reference because the _value_ of `x` **is** the reference to the object. What it does _not_ do is pass a reference to the variable (that itself is just a reference to the object), which is why you can't change a variable in the calling code by passing it to a method. I guess that my main point is simply that "pass by value of the reference" is not standard terminology.

Comment: @TedHopp Yes, I agree with you.

Comment: @arshajii, thank you. Normally I would condense the code as this is not even close to my first time of stackoverflow and I too get annoyed reading more code than necessary. However in this case, I had no idea where the error was coming from, so the entirety of the code needed to be posted.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You swapped the arguments in the call.  Type checking can't save you here.

That is, when you call a function

```
public static int [] getScores(int [] exams, int [] quizzes, int [] labs) {...}
```

with

```
int[] countarr = getScores(quizzes, exams, labs);
```

you can't expect the results to make any sense!

Comment: Good eye! What _could_ save OP would be to define a class that had the quizzes/exams/labs as fields.

Comment: @TedHopp Then he could trip up on the constructor call :)

Comment: Exactly.  This is THE main use case for named method/function parameters in programming languages

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik - Heh. The idea, though, would be to never pass separate arrays anywhere, including into a constructor.

Comment: @TedHopp Or any same-typed objects. For example, a single array of objects representing the triple (exam,quiz,lab) is just as slippery. What could save him here is to avoid positional arguments. For example, pass a map String->array, use a custom class with a builder pattern, etc.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik - A class like I suggested with `int[]` fields `quizzes`, `exams`, and `labs` would act exactly like a map `String->array`, but with a fixed set of keys known at compile time.

Comment: @TedHopp But the key is in the initalization of such class: a constructor call with `(quizzes,exams,labs)` will obviously not gain anything, but a builder pattern: `builder.quizzes(quizzes).exams(exams).labs(labs)` will.

Comment: Better really to have `Exam`, `Quiz`, and `Lab` classes, which extend `Assignment`, then you just need to pass in one `List<Assignment>` object and hide the specific behavior (like the assignment weight) with inheritance.

Comment: I think the design principle here is that whenever possible, your arrays should be at the top level.  An array of { quiz, exam, lab } is better than three arrays (if the logical data model supports such a transformation).  Even then you could accidentally swap the single ints in those constructor calls.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik - No, no, no. You create the object with a constructor that takes only an array size argument. You then fill the fields of the class directly (or perhaps through mutator methods), rather than creating separate arrays and then passing them to a constructor (or even to a builder factory).

Comment: @TedHopp You didn't imply anything like that before, but now that you've explained it, it seems like quite a crooked design. Having an object represent each type of assignment, with all the logic done polymorhpically against a common interface feels much more natural. Or at least one general class with the property of score multiplier. Then you can have a collection of such objects instead of three fixed fields.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik - I was implying exactly that before. You were making assumptions. I also fail to why a collection with keys is better than a class with fixed fields when the keys are also fixed. In fact, I don't see much difference at all, unless you needed to do things like loop over the keys. I also don't see how polymorphism helps here. The multiplier logic belongs in the class (or collection) that groups everything together, not in each of the types individually. (Weights of exam/lab/class may be different for different courses.) By the way, what's a "crooked design"?

Comment: @TedHopp 1) Yes, you probably do need to loop over all the keys because each key receives the same treatment. 2) There are two options for the calculation: parameterize a fixed formula or leverage polymorphism to allow any kind of formula for each assignment type. Which to use depends on the amount of flexibility you need. For example, you may want some non-linearity involved. 3) "Crooked" is not a defining characteristic of a design, but a quality assigned to it. So the question could be "what kind of design would you call crooked?", but I think the attribute is  self-explanatory.

Comment: Thanks guys. Can't believe I didn't notice it, but no wonder it was behaving weird. Good eye!

Answer (score 2):

There's a mismatch between the signature and what arguments you're calling it with.

```
int[] countarr = getScores(quizzes, exams, labs);

public static int [] getScores(int [] exams, int [] quizzes, int [] labs){
```

You've apparently mixed up the arguments